# Custom Dialog Didnt Show Icon Outside Layout

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have make a custom dialog but it doesn't work as what i expect, been looking through other answer in stack overflow here is my method

```
        val mDialogView =
        LayoutInflater.from(mFragment.requireContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.dialog_confirm,
            null
        )
        val mBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(mFragment.requireContext(),R.style.CustomDialog).setView(mDialogView)
        val mAlertDialog = mBuilder.show()
        mAlertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
        mAlertDialog.window!!.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
        val dialogBinding = DialogConfirmBinding.bind(mDialogView)
```

and the result:
[picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kLNV.png)

i did found a answer work for me but i have no idea to combine with view binding

```
        val dialog = Dialog(mFragment.requireContext())
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_confirm)
        dialog.window!!.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
        dialog.show()
```

result that work for me:
[picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKvPo.png)

but even i setContentView(dialogbinding.root) the result will back to the first picture.